# Laravel: Filter query based on many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

I have two objects, say `Post` and `Tag` with a many-to-many relationship.

Based on a collection of tags, I want to select all posts that match either (1) any tag or (2) all tags in the collection.

Is there a simple way to perform these queries in Laravel (preferably using Eloquent)?

Answer (score -1):

You query the tags you want, then you can loop through each tags posts with

```
$tags = Tag::where('name','=','Laravel 4')->get();
foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    foreach($tag->posts as $post)
    {
        echo $post->name;
    }
}
```

This is assuming you have your relationship and your pivot table setup appropriately.

You can also eager load certain tags based on certain posts...

`$posts = Post::where('name','=','Some post name')
                       ->with(array('tags' => function($query)
                           {
                               $query = $query->where('tag_name','=','Laravel');
                           }))->get();`

```
foreach($posts as $post)
{
    foreach($post->tags as $tag)
    {
        echo $tag->tag_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But in the end I want a collection of posts, that can be sorted. Your solution only gives me a list of post names (or objects), sorted by tag. Also: I don't quite understand how the second part of your answer is relevant to my question. Could you add a little more explanation?

Comment: When using my second example, it would find all posts with the name of 'Some post name' and then for each of those posts it will find tags where the tag_name is 'Laravel'.  It's probably exactly what you need because you'd also be able to sort those as well with `$query = $query->sortBy('name');`